# C# TLS session disconnects

Tags: c#, session, ssl

I have a Client(s)/Server TCP scenario with TLS connections written in C#.

The clients are failing to deliver messages after they go quiet and resume (inactivity time ~25 minutes). But If I keep the clients chatting (every 30 seconds) there is no problem.

Neither the client nor the server are seeing a disconnection, but traffic stops flowing (TLS Session break??? I am just guessing here).

I need to keep the connection in place because the server needs to response back at any time.

The server has KeepAlives every 5 minutes once the TCP socket connects and TLS authenticates

Q1) Is there a way to configure the **SslStream** or the socket in C# to use TicketKeys and reuse the session?

Q2) If the problem is not **Session reuse**, if I use a WireShark or NetMonitor, what should I be looking for, to determine why the traffic is no longer flowing even if the parties believe they are connected?

Thx

Comment: This does not answer Q1 and Q2 but might explain what you see: It might be some firewall or stateful packet filter or NAT router in between with a short timeout for the states. Once the state is closed no more traffic on this connection will pass the middlebox. To keep it open you need either application level keep alive or a short TCP keep alive.

Comment: Thanks Steffen what you are saying makes sense but the problem doesn't manifest if I use TCP sockets without TLS. I don't know if my server (Azure VM) is keeping a session key cache, but I suspect that is what is timing out.

Comment: A session cache is for SSL session spanning multiple TCP connections, i.e. to resume a session which was started in another TCP connection. So it should have no effect in your case where the timeout is inside a single TCP connection.

Comment: As for Q2: look at both sides if the packet gets send on one side and received on the other side. If it is send on one side and not received on the other then the problem is caused by some middlebox.

Answer (score -1):

- Don't set timeout on server and client

  ```
  sslStream.ReadTimeout = 5000;
  sslStream.WriteTimeout = 5000;
  ```
- Set big timeout
- Implement something like: *Ping/Pong* heartbeat command and in client, in separate thread, send Ping to server every X seconds